# Pivot Grid display data fields in row area

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, pivot

I got a request to change the devExpress pivot grid, so that it shows only one column per size, the values should be displayed as rows. Please see the images as its hard to explain in writing.

Current setup:
[image]

Desired output (done in excel):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`PivotGridOptionsDataField.Area`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridOptionsDataField_Areatopic) property. If you set this value to [`PivotDataArea.RowArea`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotDataAreaEnumtopic) then you get what you want:
[image]